# PHP variable not updating in while loop

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am writing a small PHP script to generate a CSV file based on customer invoices. I'm noticing that on my echo line to generate the order, only $order_date is updating. The other variables aren't changing. If I echo $rowprops[1], I do see that I am walking the rowset correctly.

I don't know enough about PHP to spot my mistake.

```
if ($result_daterange_orders = mysqli_query($con, $query_daterange_orders))
{
echo "Date,Order #,Gross,VAT,Net,VAT registration notes";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_daterange_orders)) {
    $order_id = $row[0];
$query_is_order_eu = "SELECT 1 from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = " . $order_id . " AND meta_key = '_shipping_country' AND meta_value IN
(
'AT',
'BE',
'BG',
'CH',
'CY',
'CZ',
'DE',
'DK',
'EE',
'ES',
'FI',
'FR',
'GB',
'GR',
'HR',
'HU',
'IE',
'IT',
'LT',
'LU',
'LV',
'MT',
'NL',
'PL',
'PT',
'RO',
'SE',
'SI',
'SK',
'IM',
'MC'
)";
if ($result_is_order_eu = mysqli_query($con, $query_is_order_eu)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_is_order_eu) != 0) { /* Order is in EU */
        mysqli_free_result($result_is_order_eu);
        $properties_query = "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = " . $order_id . " AND meta_key = '_wcpdf_invoice_date'
            OR meta_key = '_wcpdf_invoice_number' OR meta_key = '_order_tax' OR meta_key = '_order_shipping_tax'
            OR meta_key = '_order_total'";
        if ($result_properties = mysqli_query($con, $properties_query)) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result_properties) != 0) { /* We have properties */
            $order_date;
            $invoice_id;
            $gross;
            $vat_total = 0;
            $vat_calced = 0;
            $net;
            $vnotes = "";
            while ($rowprops = mysqli_fetch_row($result_properties)) {
                //echo $rowprops[1]; different every time
                if (strcmp($rowprops[0], "_wcpdf_invoice_number") === 0) 
                    $invoice_id = $rowprops[1]; 
                if (strcmp($rowprops[0], "_wcpdf_invoice_date") === 0)
                    $order_date = $rowprops[1];
                if (strcmp($rowprops[0], "_order_total") === 0)
                    $gross = $rowprops[1];
                if (strcmp($rowprops[0], "_order_tax") === 0) {
                    $vat_total += $rowprops[1];
                    $vat_calced +=1;
                }
                if (strcmp($rowprops[0], "_order_shipping_tax") === 0) {
                    $vat_total += $rowprops[1];
                    $vat_calced +=1;
                }
                if ($vat_calced == 2 && $vat_total === 0) /* VAT free customer */
                    $vnotes = "Order ID " . $order_id . " is VAT exempt. Registration number is "; 
                if ($vat_calced == 2 && $vat_total !== 0) /* Work out bottom line */
                    $net = $gross - $vat_total;
            }
            // Format: Date, Order #, Gross, VAT, Net, VAT reg notes //
            mysqli_free_result($result_properties);
            echo $order_date . "," . $invoice_id . "," . $gross . "," . "," . $vat_total . "," . $net . "," . $vnotes . "\n";   
            }
        }

    }
}
}
mysqli_free_result($result_daterange_orders);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks -- I'm not sure why only $order_date is updating. At first I was concerned that I was repeating the loop but if you check my commented echo, it prints a unique value every time.

Comment: No update query is there

Comment: Which loop are you talking about?  The inner one?  How exactly are you examining those variables for updates?  It doesn't look like any of them are actually used for anything.

Comment: I am not trying to update the database, so there is no update query. I am trying to echo the variable values to generate a CSV file.

WooCommerce has a structure much akin to this:

post_id (order id), meta_key, meta_value.

I want the order date, invoice id, gross cost, vat_total and net as well as some other variables

So for all rows returned correlating to a post_id (an order), I strcmp meta_key to find out what kind of data is stored, and assign the value to the variable. When I've exhausted all rows, I want to print the values for that order.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're echoing after the loop has been run through entirely, and therefore each iteration of fetch_row is not being echoed, only the last fetch.

Your outer loop is on order_date, so that will change because echo is inside that loop, while it remains outside the inner loop which is iterating through your other variable info.

```
while ($rowprops = mysqli_fetch_row($result_properties)) {
    if ()...
    if ()...
    //echo is inside this inner loop so vars will update with every iteration
    echo $order_date . "," . $invoice_id . "," . $gross . "," . "," . $vat_total . "," . $net . "," . $vnotes . "\n";   
}
mysqli_free_result($result_properties);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

If I put echo $order_date... after the if() within the while loop, I still only get order date properties, and sometimes get unknown variables. I guess then I will need to have another variable called $fields_checked and if ($fields_checked < number of fields I want to check), don't echo, and do a ++ each time I successfully strcmp?

Comment: Also not sure how my outer loop is on order_date, order_date is populated from my inner while loop with strcmp() as well.

Comment: $fields_checked to track the iteration doesn't work.

Comment: I'd bracket all your if statements, and then in your inner loop ifs, echo or var_dump($rowprops[1]) to make sure youre getting valid values at those points.  Because if you aren't, there's a deeper problem, something with your sql or database values.

Comment: I've already added an echo($rowprops[1] and { } around each strcmp() and can confirm I am getting a unique value each time. It's the assignment, or where I'm choosing to echo the assignment that's not working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, It's hard to say what exactly the problem is, as there are nested loops, and inner loop result depends on what data is posted to a method. Eg. `$query_daterange_orders` - is this variable always the same?

Try to break the problem into smaller parts.
1 - starting from line 1 - make sure that $query_daterange_orders is always the same. and then go deeper, checking results on the next line.

Comment: $query_daterange_orders is always the same on execution:

$query_daterange_orders = "SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_type ='shop_order' AND post_status ='wc-completed' OR post_status = 'wc-processing' AND post_date_gmt BETWEEN " . $DATE1 . " AND " . $DATE2;

Comment: The dates are hard coded.

$DATE1="01/12/2015";
$DATE2="29/02/2016";

Comment: I think I'm going to rewrite this in Python. I think the issue has something to do with PHP's variable handling.

Comment: Try to var_dump($order_id) along with //echo $rowprops[1]; different every time. Making sure that $order_id is related to same $rowprops everytime.

Comment: dump $order_id and $rowprops

Comment: $var_dump shows both $order_id and $rowprops are updating. I get string(3) for $order_id and it's updating and i get array(2) for each order which is valid. As I say, if I echo($rowprops[1]) right there, it's valid, the only reason I need to store in a var is so I can print the output in the order I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106271/discussion-between-user3526827-and-chupakabra-hunter).

Comment: I will rewrite this in another language. PHP does not appear to yield consistent results with PHP 5.6.17 from Ubuntu 14.04 repository. Thanks to Chupakabra for trying to help via chat.